# How to kill all process except one, unless there is one process

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script like this:

```
pid = $(ps -ef | grep my-service | awk '{print $2}')
```

Which gives me a PID of the process running `my-service`. I want to update my script to handle multiple processes running, and to kill all old `my-service` processes except the most recent one. But if there is only one process run, just kill it. How do I do that?

Comment: Does `pgrep -f my-service` matches your process?

Comment: Yes it does. I'll update that.

Answer (score 3):

`pgrep` (and `pkill`) has some useful parameters for this task, like `-c` (`--count`) to count the number of processes and `-n` (`--newest`) to get only the newest pid. (`man pgrep` for more)

So we could use this `case` statement. For no pids returned, we exit, for one we kill this process. If more than one processes are found, we exclude the newest pid with a `grep -v` against all the pids and then pipe to `kill`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

die="my-service"

case $(pgrep -cf "$die") in
    0) exit 0 ;;
    1) pkill -f "$die" ;;
    *) grep -v $(pgrep -nf "$die") <(pgrep -f "$die") | xargs kill ;;
esac
```

Note: In the above, `-f` parameter is used, this is matching the full command, it should not be used if we want to match only the process name. From `man pgrep`:

> -f, --full
>
> The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming procps-ng's `ps` and an unmodified `$IFS`, you could do:

```
set -- $(ps -o pid= --sort=-start_time -C my-service)
case $# in
  (0) ;;
  (1) kill "$1";;
  (*) shift; kill "$@"
esac
```

`set` assigns the *positional parameters* (`$1`, `$2`...) to the pids of processes whose name is `my-service`, sorted in reverse by `start_time` (most recently started first).

Then based on their number (`$#`), we do nothing if it's 0, kill it if it's 1, and for any other number, `shift` to discard the youngest, and kill the rest.

(note that `ps -C name` matches *exactly* on the full process name, not on the arg list reported by `ps -f`)

Comment: What's the difference when using `()` or `)` for case? I see in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) it is described only in the syntax pattern.

Comment: @thanasisp, it's mostly a matter of taste. The Bourne shell only did `)`. POSIX specifies both. IIRC `)` trips some shells when the `case` statement is inside `$(...)` (which the Bourne shell didn't have either). I much prefer `()`.

Comment: @thanasisp, see also [the POSIX rationale section about that](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_09_14).

Comment: Wow, this was absolutely brilliant. Could you explain a bit, what the first line is doing with `set --`?

Comment: @RakibFiha, see edit.